# using jquery datatable for dynamic table rows

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data, datatables

I am constructing the table dynamically using jquery/javascript. I have a several links based on which the table body will be generated dynamically using json/jquery.

I like to integrate the jquery datatable with the dynamically created table. How can i attach the `.dataTable()` for the dynamically created rows.

When i tried to use in document.ready, the table holds the values of the first time created table.

My javascript look like:

```
    function GetProducts(Id) {
       $('#tProductListBody').html('');

       $.getJSON("/Product/GetProducts/?t=" + new Date(), { catId: Id },
        function(data) {
            var _productsBodyHtml = '';
            if (data != null && data != false) {
            for (i in data) {
                var _product = data[i];
                _productsBodyHtml += '<tr><td>' + _product.ProductName + '</td>';
                _productsBodyHtml += '<td>' + _product.QuantityInHand + '</td><td>' + _product.Price + '</td></tr>';
            }
            }
            $('#tProductListBody').html(_productsBodyHtml);
            $('#tProductList').dataTable();
        });
   }
```

With the above js function, it'll add the datatable for each click of the links.

`dataTable()` is a jquery plugin which gives sort, paging and search functionalities to the html table. The plugin dynamically adds textbox for searching and a pager for paging.

The problem i am facing is When i click on one of links, i build the table dynamically and the `dataTable()` adds up again another textbox and pager and gives previous created result in search and paging. I need to avoid this as well the `dataTable()` functionality should work for the latest dynamic table content

How can i rephrase this js function for the datatable not to get added more than once and which applies the latest dynamic table?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the  [`fnReloadAjax`](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax) custom function of the Datatables plugin ...

Comment: Is there any sample to refer "sAjaxSource" and "fnReloadAjax" in asp.net mvc(C#).